How can I get a global variable's assigned value in libcst?
I want to parse the following Python file in libcst:
MY_VAR = "my_val"

def my_func(arg):
  # ...

my_func(MY_VAR)

Using libcst I'm able to get the "MY_VAR" as a string:
with open(pipeline_file_path, "r") as f:
    src_tree: cst.Module = cst.parse_module(f.read())
    wrapper = cst.metadata.MetadataWrapper(src_tree)

    scopes = set(wrapper.resolve(cst.metadata.ScopeProvider).values())
    for scope in scopes:
        for assignment in scope.assignments:
            if isinstance(assignment, cst.metadata.Assignment):
                node = assignment.node
                print(assignment.node.value) # prints MY_VAR

But I want the right side of the assignment; how can I print "my_val"?

You should be looping over the nodes, not the scopes. Look for a node whose type is libcst.Assign. The value will be node.value. See https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodes.html#libcst.Assign

Barmar's comment is the correct answer, here's my CSTVisitor code:
def on_leave(self, node):
    if isinstance(node, cst.Assign):
        left = None
        right = None
        for child in node.children:
            if isinstance(child, cst.AssignTarget):
                left = child.target.value
            elif isinstance(child, cst.SimpleString):
                right = child.evaluated_value

        if left and right:
            self.globals[left] = right

